# Kill an .exe batch script and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exe, kill, taskkill

I'm trying to make a script in PowerShell which calls a .bat (& .\test.bat) and this .bat needs to execute a .exe (or many), wait a timeout, and kill it (or them).

For this purpose I did (in a loop):

```
start %1
timeout 5 > nul
taskkill /f /im %1
exit 0
```

Everything is launched and the timeout is good but the cmd is never closed.

How could I do it?

Comment: Tried your code and invoked it as `& .\test.bat calc.exe` - works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try use ex: 
    Stop-Process -processname notepad.exe